# Magento 2 - Authorize.net Direct Post - Checkout Fail

Tags: magento2, authorize.net

NOTE: A client recently approached our team wanting to have a new site built on Magento 2. They currently have a site on Magento 1.9. This error we are having is in reference to the new site in development.

Checkout works with other payment methods, excluding Authorize.net Direct Post which is where the problem lies.
I have entered in the correct API Login ID, Transaction Key, and MD5 Hash. Yet when attempting to checkout, I am getting this error at the top of the form.

[image]

Inspection of the debug.log reveals this,

```
[2017-06-16 20:57:49] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"https://www.catalinayachtsstore.com/m5/en/authorizenet/directpost_payment/place/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["catalog_product_464","FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-06-16 20:57:49] main.DEBUG: array (
  'request' => 
  array (
    'x_version' => '3.1',
    'x_delim_data' => 'FALSE',
    'x_relay_response' => 'TRUE',
    'x_test_request' => 'FALSE',
    'x_login' => '****',
    'x_method' => 'CC',
    'x_relay_url' => 'https://www.catalinayachtsstore.com/m5/en/authorizenet/directpost_payment/response',
    'x_type' => 'AUTH_CAPTURE',
    'x_fp_sequence' => '934',
    'x_invoice_num' => '11000000015',
    'x_amount' => 1.0,
    'x_currency_code' => 'USD',
    'x_tax' => '0.00',
    'x_freight' => '0.00',
    'x_first_name' => 'Firstname',
    'x_last_name' => 'Lastname',
    'x_company' => 'Royal Blue Web',
    'x_address' => '123 First St',
    'x_city' => 'Fake City',
    'x_state' => 'Michigan',
    'x_zip' => '49123',
    'x_country' => '',
    'x_phone' => '1234567890',
    'x_fax' => '',
    'x_cust_id' => '',
    'x_customer_ip' => '99.999.9.999',
    'x_customer_tax_id' => '',
    'x_email' => 'placeholder@gmail.com',
    'x_email_customer' => '0',
    'x_merchant_email' => 'fake@gmail.net',
    'x_po_num' => '',
    'x_fp_timestamp' => 1497646669,
    'x_fp_hash' => 'f2e1a37366ed079e9031af1914df6216',
  ),
) {"is_exception":false} []
[2017-06-16 20:57:52] main.DEBUG: array (
  'response' => 
  array (
    'x_response_code' => '1',
    'x_response_reason_code' => '1',
    'x_response_reason_text' => 'This transaction has been approved.',
    'x_avs_code' => 'Y',
    'x_auth_code' => '02543B',
    'x_trans_id' => '40149604980',
    'x_method' => 'CC',
    'x_card_type' => 'MasterCard',
    'x_account_number' => 'XXXX1234',
    'x_first_name' => 'Firstname',
    'x_last_name' => 'Lastname',
    'x_company' => 'Royal Blue Web',
    'x_address' => '123 First st',
    'x_city' => 'Fake City',
    'x_state' => 'Michigan',
    'x_zip' => '49123',
    'x_country' => '',
    'x_phone' => '1234567890',
    'x_fax' => '',
    'x_email' => 'adam.ncmich.edu@gmail.com',
    'x_invoice_num' => '11000000015',
    'x_description' => '',
    'x_type' => 'auth_capture',
    'x_cust_id' => '',
    'x_ship_to_first_name' => '',
    'x_ship_to_last_name' => '',
    'x_ship_to_company' => '',
    'x_ship_to_address' => '',
    'x_ship_to_city' => '',
    'x_ship_to_state' => '',
    'x_ship_to_zip' => '',
    'x_ship_to_country' => '',
    'x_amount' => '1.00',
    'x_tax' => '0.00',
    'x_duty' => '0.00',
    'x_freight' => '0.00',
    'x_tax_exempt' => 'FALSE',
    'x_po_num' => '',
    'x_MD5_Hash' => '8F32AA3F4E032A2F41218CDEAF75C573',
    'x_SHA2_Hash' => '',
    'x_cvv2_resp_code' => 'M',
    'x_cavv_response' => '',
    'x_test_request' => 'false',
    'controller_action_name' => 'directpost_payment',
    'is_secure' => '1',
  ),
) {"is_exception":false} []
```

Trying to decipher the message, It makes me think the MD5 Hash entered does not match. But I have created new credentials multiple times, and the API creds work on the current live version of the site. (The magento 1.9 version).

The site is not in maintenance mode.

The site is in default mode. (Not development or production).

Test mode is set to NO under the authorize.net payment gateway settings.
Debug mode is set to YES under the authorize.net payment gateway settings.

I exhausted all trial and error methods before resorting to stackexchange for help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this.
I am leaving this question up, and posting my answer to the problem as to help others who may have the same issue.

The MD5 Hash string I set in Authorize.net was too long.
After setting the MD5 Hash to a random 10 character string (upper/lowercase and numbers), it worked.